# manually set type face attribute for ListPreference?

Tags: android

I am working with a ListPreference and want to set the type face of the title to 'serif' and the summary to 'sans'. Is there a way to do this, i.e. to set the type faces manually?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/).

Edit 1:

```
<ListPreference 
   android:title="my title"
   android summary="my summary"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I would set the desired text attribute for the ListPreference Title versus the ListPreference Summary, specifically? It's not clear to me how I actually set these attributes for a ListPreference object.

Comment: Thanks again. However, I am trying to set the typeface and color of the text displayed for title and summary, separately (i.e. different color for title, different color for summary), not the strings.